# C# - Inicialização de um array/list

Tags: c#, array, lista

Gostaria de saber se tem como instanciar um vetor de tamanho n e já inicializar ele com um valor específico. (Sem usar um for para isso)

Por exemplo, gostaria de instanciar um vetor, que vai ter tamanho 100 e todos os índices com o valor -1.

(Essa dúvida serve para um vetor de int[], e também um List de int.).

Comment: Penso que sem um `for` não terá grandes hipóteses de inicializar um `array` assim tão grande manualmente...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar um workaround para criar esse array com a seguinte instrução:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select((y) => -1).ToArray();
```

Note que há um overhead para fazer isso, mas resolve o que você quer, você pode criar um factory method se o uso for recorrente.

O exemplo disso funcionando está no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/220VpH)

Answer (score 1):

Pode se criar um método de extensão para popular suas coleções. Crie uma classe estática com um método estático para se tornar um método de extensão:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Método para popular a coleção de dados
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TypeValue">Tipo de dados do valor que vai ser preenchido</typeparam>
    /// <param name="collection">Coleção de dados que será preenchida</param>
    /// <param name="value">Valor que vai ser inserido</param>
    /// <param name="indexSize">Quantos itens da coleção serão preenchidos</param>
    public static void PopularColecao<TypeValue>(this IList collection, TypeValue value, int indexSize)
    {
        if (collection.IsFixedSize)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < indexSize; i++)
                collection[i] = value;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < indexSize; i++)
                collection.Add(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Para utilizar o método de extensão, adicione o namespace da sua classe `Extensions` nos `using` e utilize da mesma forma usa as funções do Linq:

```
 List<int> lista = new List<int>();
 ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
 int[] array = new int[10];

 //A lista será populada com o valor 5 para 10 posições
 lista.PopularColecao(5, 10);

 //O array list será populado com o valor 10 para 10 posições
 arrayList.PopularColecao(10, 10);

 //O array será populado com o valor 8 para 2 posições
 array.PopularColecao(8, 2);
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela atenção Pedro Paulo! Porém a minha dúvida tinha o objetivo de justamente evitar de utilizar de qualquer estrutura de repetição para realizar este processo.

Comment: Entendi, esse exemplo foi um método que seria reutilizável em outros pontos da sua aplicação, porém se você utilizar os métodos do Linq, como por exemplo `Select, Where, Any, etc`, internamente esses métodos realizam a estrutura de repetição para iterar em seus itens. No fim, tudo precisaria de utilizar a iteração.